# Do I need to worry about "GET /?author=N HTTP/1.1" in my logs?

Tags: jquery, html, web, logging

I've seen a number of these requests for an author appear in my website access logs. They all seem to return a 200 message. 
I've searched on it, and everything I could find suggested that it's only really a problem for Wordpress users.
I don't see where the author is set in the metadata of my pages, so don't quite know if they are getting anything and of what use it'd be to someone - also, why the incremental numbers? Would a page have 20 authors? - or am I reading that incorrectly?

```
example.com:443 148.70.239.50 - - [16/Apr/2020:02:27:22 +0100] "GET /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 404 3468 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_151)"
example.com:443 148.70.239.50 - - [16/Apr/2020:02:27:23 +0100] "GET /?author=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 5875 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_151)"
example.com:443 148.70.239.50 - - [16/Apr/2020:02:27:26 +0100] "GET /?author=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 5875 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_151)"
.
.
.
example.com:443 148.70.239.50 - - [16/Apr/2020:02:27:45 +0100] "GET /?author=20 HTTP/1.1" 200 5875 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_151)"
```

Comment: You shouldn't worry about it. The internet is full of people trying to use vulnerabilities to get information of any kind. It's returning a 200 because they are fetching your homepage. I suppose the author query is something specific for wp like you said in your original post.

Answer (score -1):

The log entry GET /?author=1 HTTP/1.1 represents an HTTP GET request to the root directory of your website with a query parameter author set to 1. This is a common tactic used by malicious bots or attackers to enumerate user information from websites, particularly those using WordPress.

WordPress is known for using numerical IDs to represent different authors or users. By default, the first user created on a WordPress site is assigned an ID of 1 and is usually the admin user. By sending requests with different author IDs, an attacker can sometimes enumerate the usernames of the site's users, especially if the website has not been secured properly against user enumeration.

For example, a request like GET /?author=1 might redirect to GET /author/admin, revealing that the username for the user with ID 1 is admin.

Arnon explains in more detail about [WordPress User Enumeration Attempt](https://blog.arnonerba.com/2016/07/server-logs-explained-part-4)